# Google workspace Addon: Request File Scope for multiple files at once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am working on Drive Add-on and got stuck when I tried to request the file scope of multiple files at once.

I am using the `CardService` system via an alternate runtime (no Apps Script).

SUCCESSFUL Working case: To do the request of the file scope for one file I am doing:

```
@root_router.post('/on_items_selected', response_class=JSONResponse)
async def on_items_selected(request: Request):
    card = {"renderActions":
             {"hostAppAction": 
                {"driveAction":
                  {"requestFileScope": {"itemId": "0BzCCD97ant74akBrTHY1eUg5d0k" }
                  }
               }
             }
           }

    return card
```

How can I request the file scope of multiple files at once?

Failing request: I tried the code below but it does not work.

```py
@root_router.post('/on_items_selected', response_class=JSONResponse)
async def on_items_selected(request: Request):
    card = {"renderActions":
             {"hostAppAction": 
               {"driveAction": 
                 {"requestFileScope": [{"itemId": "0BzCCD97ant74akBrTHY1eUg5d0k"},
                                   {"itemId": "5BzCCD97ant74akBrTHY1eUg5d0k"}]
                 }
               }
             }
           }
    return card
```

See below the error:

```
Error with the add-on.
Run time error.
Expect message object but got: [{"itemId":"0BzCCD97ant74RkF0N2pRWmRUYTg"},{"itemId":"0BzCCD97ant74a1BrTHY1eUg5d0
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What error are you getting, if any? If you only request one file, does it work successfully?

Comment: Hi, it is hard to do more minimal than that. Yes, it works if I request only one file. I updated the issue and added the error message. Any idea?  thank you for your help

Comment: I think [RequestFileScope](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/reference/rpc/apps.extensions.markup#apps.extensions.markup.DriveClientActionMarkup.RequestFileScope) only allows one `itemId`. Have you been able to request multiple items when using the regular CardService?